# Vue ref/reactive with default value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

I am using Vue3 composition API. I have an input field which needs to be in sync with store, incase the data changes in store it should be updated

Code

```
const store = useStore()
const savedAge = computed(() => store.state.profile.age)
// The saved is async and can be updated at anytime in store 

const age = ref(savedAge.value)

<!-- template -->
<input v-model="age" /> // here the age is null event if savedAge value has updated in store
```

**Please note I don't want two way binding with store, I want my reactive property to update if store value has been updated**

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`watchEffect()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watcheffect) to update your local copy with `store.state.profile.age` whenever it changes. This would allow you to isolate the local copy's changes from the store until you're ready to commit:

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="age">
  <button @click="save">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const age = ref(0)
    const store = useStore()

    watchEffect(() => age.value = store.state.profile.age)

    return {
      age,
      save: () => store.commit('SAVE_AGE', age.value),
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/local-copy-of-store-state-t7hrx?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing! watchEffect did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could so `:value` and `@change`, but would be good to understand what you're trying to achieve.

```js
const store = useStore();
const ageChange = (e)=>{doSomethingWith(e.target.value)};
return {store, ageChange};
```

```html
<!-- template -->
<input :value="store.state.profile.age" @change="ageChange"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need two way binding, try binding the value attribute directly to store:

```
<input :value="store.state.profile.age" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way I won't have track if user has changed the value, I need to run some more logic if the input value is changed. I want store value as default value only, which later can be changed if user edits input.

Comment: @sandiprb how about using a local `data` that is assigned to store value initially and later updates via `v-model`? or an `@input:` call back that runs your logic when user changes value?